# Ecto.DateTime and Time Zones

Tags: datetime, elixir, ecto

Is there any way to adjust Ecto.DateTime objects for a timezone? I'd like to read an Ecto.DateTime from the database, but then adjust it for a user nominated timezone?

Also, I'd like to accept data entry and convert it back, using the timezone setting.

I've been looking for a library or a technique to do this but haven't found anything obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ecto doesn't include any such functions. There are several libraries for Elixir available which can do this. I've only used [`timex`](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex). To store Timex values in the database using Ecto, you can use the [`timex_ecto`](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex_ecto) package. Here's how you would change the timezone of a `Timex.DateTime` value to `America/Los_Angeles`:

```
iex(1)> original = Timex.now
#<DateTime(2016-08-17T06:24:03.015339Z Etc/UTC)>
iex(2)> timezone = Timex.Timezone.get("America/Los_Angeles", original)
#<TimezoneInfo(America/Los_Angeles - PDT (-07:00:00))>
iex(3)> converted = Timex.Timezone.convert(original, timezone)
#<DateTime(2016-08-16T23:24:03.015339-07:00 America/Los_Angeles)>
iex(4)> Timex.format!(original, "{ISO:Extended}")
"2016-08-17T06:24:03.015339+00:00"
iex(5)> Timex.format!(converted, "{ISO:Extended}")
"2016-08-16T23:24:03.015339-07:00"
```